# Use Sleep command to delay for a month

Tags: server, sleep

I have a server which runs a billing application and It generates bills and invoices and sends it to the registered users on a monthly basis.
I dont want to manually run this every 30 days.
I wish to automate this process by using sleep command like
***sleep 30d***

But is it good to keep this script running on the server forever and making the sleep command run in the background?

OS : CentOS 7
Purpose : Running OpenStack multi node cloud.

Comment: What OS? The right tool to do this job seems to be some task manager like crontab in Linux. You may want to update your question.

Comment: "But is it good to keep this script running on the server forever" - probably not, as the server may be restarted before the 30d expires.  Google for "task scheduler"

Comment: I am using CentOS 7 and running OpenStack cloud on it.

Comment: See this: http://serverfault.com/questions/87472/how-to-create-a-cron-job-that-runs-on-the-first-day-of-month

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `crontab` to run a script or your application with a parameter the first day of the months.

Check firts if you have any crontab GUI in your management website.
If not you should have access to the shell of your server and you should run the command `crontab -e`

It will open a text editor where you can write your scheduled tasks.

Paste this header to the top to see whay you need to write on each column:

```
# m     h  dom mon dow   command
# *     *   *   *   *  Command to be executed
# -     -   -   -   -
# |     |   |   |   |
# |     |   |   |   +----- Day of week (0-7)
# |     |   |   +------- Month (1 - 12)
# |     |   +--------- Day of month (1 - 31)
# |     +----------- Hour (0 - 23)
# +------------- Min (0 - 59)

In your case you should write
0 0 1 * * command_to_run
```

The first 0 it's for the minute
The second 0 it's for the hour
The 1 it's to say you want to run it the first day of each month
The next * says it will be ran all the months
The last * says it will be ran without regarding which day of the week it's

The last one should be your command to run.

Comment: I figured how to use crontabs. But I wish to change the destination. Like as of now, all the commands I run thru cronjobs in getting mailed to the root as a email. I dont want that. I want it to run on a particular path or any directory, I want the output to be there in the path I desire.

Comment: Create a shell script. In that shell script add the 'cd' command you need to change the path, and after that 'cd' run your application with the need parameters. To change the destination email of the crontab log add this to the crontab before your cron line MAILTO=mail@domain.com